# Extract data from Postgres DB to a JSON multilevel hierarchy structure

Tags: python, sql, json, postgresql, hierarchy

I am trying to extract data from a postgres DB to a JSON file. The problem here is, i need the data in multiple hirarchy to be loaded in the JSON file.

Any solution to achieve this in **postgres SQL query or python** will be much appreciated.

I tried to do it at one level and succeded through the json_agg() query on postgres, but not sure how to do it for more than 2 level.

This is my postgres code:

```
select
    json_build_object('column1',json_agg(
    json_build_object('name',column1,'column2',column2)))
     table1
from table;

which gives me :
[columns1:
{column2:value},
{column2:value2}
]

But what i need is:
eg: column1 column2 column3
    4       1       4
    4       4       5
    4       1       9
    2       3       7
    3       1       8
    1       1       1
    3       1       6

    output:
    [
    column1:4[{
      column2:1[{
        column3:4,
        colun3:9}]
    },
    { column2:4
      [{
        column3:5
      }]
    }]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two different variants, because your output is not valid JSON and therefore a bit difficult to guess which format you want:

Both variants below have the same query structure and are just different in the way they create JSON objects.

For more levels of hierarchy, you'd need more CTE's like `agg_c3` or you rewrite the query to use nested sub-selects if you prefer (but which get harder to read than CTE's).

**Wrapped key-value**

```sql
WITH
    my_table (col1, col2, col3) AS (
        VALUES (4,1,4), (4,4,5), (4,1,9), (2,3,7), (3,1,8), (1,1,1), (3,1,6)
    ),
    agg_c3 AS (
        SELECT col1, col2, jsonb_build_object('column3', jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('value', col3))) AS col3
        FROM my_table
        GROUP BY 1, 2
    ),
    agg_c2 AS (
        SELECT col1, jsonb_build_object('column2', jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('value', col2) || col3)) AS col2
        FROM agg_c3
        GROUP BY 1
    )
SELECT jsonb_build_object('column1', jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('value', col1) || col2)) AS json_object
FROM agg_c2
;
```

...returns:

```
{
  "column1": [
    {
      "value": 1,
      "column2": [
        {
          "value": 1,
          "column3": [
            {
              "value": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": 3,
      "column2": [
        {
          "value": 1,
          "column3": [
            {
              "value": 8
            },
            {
              "value": 6
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": 2,
      "column2": [
        {
          "value": 3,
          "column3": [
            {
              "value": 7
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "value": 4,
      "column2": [
        {
          "value": 1,
          "column3": [
            {
              "value": 4
            },
            {
              "value": 9
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "value": 4,
          "column3": [
            {
              "value": 5
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Values-only**

```sql
WITH
    my_table (col1, col2, col3) AS (
        VALUES (4,1,4), (4,4,5), (4,1,9), (2,3,7), (3,1,8), (1,1,1), (3,1,6)
    ),
    agg_c3 AS (
        SELECT col1, col2, jsonb_agg(col3) AS col3
        FROM my_table
        GROUP BY 1, 2
    ),
    agg_c2 AS (
        SELECT col1, jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(col2::text, col3)) AS col2
        FROM agg_c3
        GROUP BY 1
    )
SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(col1::text, col2)) AS json_object
FROM agg_c2
;
```

...returns:

```
[
  {
    "1": [
      {
        "1": [
          1
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "3": [
      {
        "1": [
          8,
          6
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "2": [
      {
        "3": [
          7
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "4": [
      {
        "1": [
          4,
          9
        ]
      },
      {
        "4": [
          5
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```